# PHP not posting into MYSQL data base

Tags: php, mysql

Hello just a quick question, I'm trying to get a category from a check box to post to my database but it dose not want to play the game. I'll just post a few things and we shall see if any of you lovely people can see a problem thanks.

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE `blog_post_cats` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `postID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `catID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Inside the php:

```
//add categories
if(is_array($catID)){
    foreach($_POST['catID'] as $catID){
        $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO blog_post_cats (postID,catID) VALUES (:postID,:catID)');
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':postID' => $postID,
            ':catID' => $catID
        ));
    }
}
```

The check box:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Categories</legend>

    <?php   

    $stmt2 = $db->query('SELECT catID, catTitle FROM blog_cats ORDER BY catTitle');
    while($row2 = $stmt2->fetch()){

        if(isset($_POST['catID'])){

            if(in_array($row2['catID'], $_POST['catID'])){
                $checked="checked='checked'";
            }else{
                $checked = null;
            }
        }

        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='catID[]' value='".$row2['catID']."' $checked> ".$row2['catTitle']."<br />";
    }

    ?>

</fieldset>
```

I do see the categories but when I post it dose not add it to the post any help will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: $catID is undefined and not an array ever

Comment: This a total mess. No form submitted, so where `$_POST['catID']` can come from? How `$catID` can exist and be an array, while next line it's an element of `$_POST['catID']`? Nohting can work here: try to clean all that first.

Comment: That isn't all of my code but thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your problem starts with your `if` statement.

```
//add categories
 if(is_array($catID)){
 foreach($_POST['catID'] as $catID){
    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO blog_post_cats (postID,catID) VALUES (:postID,:catID)');
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':postID' => $postID,
        ':catID' => $catID
    ));
 }
}
```

should be

```
//add categories
if(is_array($_POST['catID'])){
    foreach($_POST['catID'] as $catID){
       $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO blog_post_cats (postID,catID) VALUES (:postID,:catID)');
       $stmt->execute(array(
           ':postID' => $postID,
           ':catID' => $catID
       ));
     }
}
```